# AEM - Making Sling Mapping and URL rewriting using link Rewriter/Transformer work together

Tags: aem, sling

We have Sling rewriter transformer to resolve some links which can only be resolved during render time. However using this transformer breaks another sling:mapping configuration that we have. It has outbound link mappings to hide internal links but because of the transformer, it is showing the complete URL. Is there a way we can make both of them work in tandem ? I want the sling mapping to run after the transformer. Is it possible ? Does the transformer get higher priority ?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to fix your rewriter transformer.

sling mapping are used by ResourceResolver to map and resolve resources (path <--> node in jcr), and are part of sling. they do not "run" before or after anything.